# How to show transition in d3 on one path after another?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, frontend

Example: I have path P1, P2, P3 and P4. I have a animation running on path P1 and once animation over Path P1 ends i want to start animation on Path P2 and same as once animation on path P2 ends i want to start animation over path P3. Give that path P1, P2, P3, P4 are not connected with each other!

Comment: A single path can be interrupted with M (move to) directive. Just merge all your paths into one without being connected visually: "M 0,0 L 100,100 M 200,200 L 300,300" e.t.c

Comment: Hi thanks for the info! But can you please demonstrate how we can achieve that on code level!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(20,20)">
    <path fill="none" stroke="lightgrey"
      d="M 50,0 Q 100,0 100,50 M 50,100 Q 0,100 0,50" />
    <circle r="5" fill="red">
      <animateMotion dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"
        path="M 50,0 Q 100,0 100,50 M 50,100 Q 0,100 0,50" />
    </circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the code snippet! I really appreciate the effort you put in this answer! But i am facing trouble while trying to use animateMotion via d3.js. Can you please show some example with d3.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a D3 example:

```js
const path = 'M 50,0 Q 100,0 100,50 M 50,100 Q 0,100 0,50';
const g = d3.select('g');
g.append('path')
  .attr('d', path)
  .style('stroke', 'blue')
  .style('fill', 'none');
  
const circle = g.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 5)
  .style('fill', 'red');
circle.append('animateMotion')
  .attr('dur', '3s')
  .attr('repeatCount', 'indefinite')
  .attr('path', path);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <g transform="translate(20,20)">
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael it helped alot!

Comment: @PragyanshDwivedi please mark or upvote the correct answer

Comment: I already did that! but my reputation is below 15 so it will be counted in upvotes but doesn't effect as public view